# How to pass the data get from Home widget to it's child widgets in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, storage, flutter-dependencies

I am developing an app for a community with login, signup, meetings and chats in flutter. After login successful, the route goes to Home which has five bottom navigation. I am using Firebase in this app for Authentication and Firestore.

I would like to fetch the data once when Home Component started and pass the data to other five bottom navigation bar components.
Now I am fetching the data whenever I switched between navigation components. This increase the Firestore reads.

I tried passing the data through components using constructor variables. But this doesn't work. It shows error that data can't be passed to bottom navigation components Here is my code.

> Home.dart

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
  User currentUser;
  String userId;
  Home({this.currentUser, this.userId});
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  CurrentUser userInfo;
  DocumentSnapshot doc;
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  List<String> upcoming_seven_days;
  FirestoreService _firestoreService = FirestoreService();
  static const TextStyle optionStyle =
      TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);
  static List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    Dashboard(),
    MeetingList(),
    EventList(),
    Chat(),
    Profile(),
  ];

  static const List<Widget> _appBarText = <Widget>[
    Text(
      'Dashboard',
      style: TextStyle(
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
        fontSize: 26,
      ),
    ),
    Text(
      'Meetings',
      style: TextStyle(
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
        fontSize: 26,
      ),
    ),
    Text(
      'Events',
      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w300, fontSize: 26),
    ),
    Text(
      'Chat',
      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w300, fontSize: 26),
    ),
    Text(
      'Profile',
      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w300, fontSize: 26),
    ),
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    //setCurrentUserID(widget.currentUser.uid);

    //setCurrentUserData(doc.data());
  }

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: _appBarText.elementAt(_selectedIndex)),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
        width: double.maxFinite,
        child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.dashboard),
              title: Text('Dashboard'),
              backgroundColor: Colors.black),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.people),
              title: Text('Meetings'),
              backgroundColor: Colors.black),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_view_day),
              title: Text('Events'),
              backgroundColor: Colors.black),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.chat),
              title: Text('Chat'),
              backgroundColor: Colors.black),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.person),
              title: Text('Profile'),
              backgroundColor: Colors.black),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.lightBlue[200],
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
        elevation: 8.0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is where I fetch the data from Firestore whenever the user switch to Meeting list component. I don't want to do like that. Rather, I want to pass the respective data from Home to other components. And it should be snapshot, so it can listen to changes.

> MeetingList.dart

```
class MeetingList extends StatelessWidget {
  var userInfo;
  FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  Future getuserinfo() async {
    // final uid = firebaseAuth.currentUser.uid;
    // userinfo = await firestoreService.getCurrentUserInfo(uid);
    // userinfo = userinfo.data().length;
    // //print(userinfo);
    // return uid;
    final uid = firebaseAuth.currentUser.uid;
    DocumentSnapshot user = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('userProfiles')
        .doc(uid)
        .get();
    userInfo = user.data();
    return userInfo;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CollectionReference meetings =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('meetings');
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: getuserinfo(),
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return LoadingIndicator();
        } else {
          return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream: meetings.snapshots(),
            builder:
                (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text('Something went wrong');
              }

              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return LoadingIndicator();
              }

              return new ListView(
                children: snapshot.data.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                  String meetingRole = document.data()['role'];
                  var userRole = userInfo['role'];
                  print(userRole);
                  if (meetingRole == 'all' || meetingRole == userRole) {
                    return Meeting_Card(
                      meeting: document.data(),
                    );
                  } else {
                    return Container();
                  }
                }).toList(),
              );
            },
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Your help would be so much helpful for the community.

Comment: You will have to fetch all the APIs in the `initState` method of `Home` screen & initialize all the variables that you are passing to the children widgets inside `setState`.

Comment: @RaviSinghLodhi , but the components I calling in Home widget doesn't accept the data.

Comment: @RaviSinghLodhi However, I will try as you said.

Comment: Will you pass data from `Home.dart`  to `MeetingList.dart`?

Comment: I did .. I am getting this error `The instance member 'meetings' can't be accessed in an initializer.
Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Provider` package for this, which is a wrapper around the `InheritedWidget` in flutter.

> `InheritedWidget` is used to efficiently propagate information down
> the tree, without having to pass them through various constructors
> down the widget tree.

You can find more information about `InheritedWidget` [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html).

> `Provider` package is wrapper around `InheritedWidget` to make them
> easier to use and more reusable.

More information on `Provider` in the documentation [here](https://pub.dev/packages/provider)

**To implement your solution using `Provider`:**
Create a `ChangeNotifier` class called `UserProvider` to hold the data you want common between all the children widgets:

```
class UserProvider extends ChangeNotifier {

  User userInfo;
  
  Future getuserinfo() async {
    // final uid = firebaseAuth.currentUser.uid;
    // userinfo = await firestoreService.getCurrentUserInfo(uid);
    // userinfo = userinfo.data().length;
    // //print(userinfo);
    // return uid;
    final uid = firebaseAuth.currentUser.uid;
    DocumentSnapshot user = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('userProfiles')
        .doc(uid)
        .get();
    userInfo = user.data();
    return userInfo;
  }

}
```

Now wrap your `Home` Widget in a `ChangeNotifierProvider` widget:

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<UserProvider>(
      lazy: false,
      create: (context) => UserProvider(),
      child: Home(),
    );
  }

}
```

Now you can access the content of the `UserProvider` class from wherever down the same widget tree **(Any of the tabs)** by using:

```
/// Get an instance of the UserProvider in the ancestors of the current widget tree like this.
UserProvider userProvider = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context);

/// Call any method inside the UserProvider class like this
userProvider.getUserInfo();

/// access any data variables inside the UserProvider class like this.
User userInfo = userProvider.userInfo;
```

You can also take a look at the `Consumer` and `Selector` widgets in the provider package, which provide an efficient ways to redraw the UI based on certain parameters of the `ChangeNotifier` class, when the `notifyListeners()` methid is called from the `ChangeNotifier` class.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This will help.

Comment: I created instance of **UserProvider** in Home widget I want to call. When I initialized this --> `UserProvider userProvider = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context);`,  I am getting this error `The instance member 'context' can't be accessed in an initializer.`

Comment: Are you doing this `UserProvider userProvider = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context);` in the `initState()`?

Comment: Yes! I need to call it in init state before build

Comment: I think this will work -> create a function of UserProvider accepting context and call the function in init state?

Comment: The member variable `context` can be accessed during `initState` but can't be used for everything. Can you share some code showing why you need to call it in `initState`?

Comment: Code can't be put in comment. But here it is. Home widget has five bottom navigation bar (Dashboard, Meetings, Events, Chat and Profile). What is happening now is whenever use switch to anyone of the tabs, the required data for each tab fetches again and again. I want to fetch the data from firestore only once when Home starts. This could save firestore reads.

Comment: You can add your code as an update to the question itself. Btw there is no need to initialise: `UserProvider userProvider = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context)`; the inistance of `UserProvider` already gets initialised in the `create()` of `ChangeNotifierProvider`. `Provider.of<UserProvider>(context)` just gives you a reference to the same instance. So you can use it anywhere.